# How to call a .NET Core 3.0 gRPC Server application with bloomRPC?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, asp.net-core-3.0

For this question, it is relevant to know that I do have ASP .NET Core experience, do have REST experience but I am a newbee when it comes to gRPC. In addition, I am working on Windows right now.

At first, I created a server project and a client project as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

This works fine and exactly as expected and documented.

Logically, I want to be able to call my server project from a tool (as many developer use a tool -such as Postman- to test their REST Api Server project). I am failing when it comes to this so maybe someone can explain what am I doing wrong and how to resolve my problem? I am using bloomRPC and I get an error I do not understand (my server application is available).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow steps below:

1. Make sure `RpcServer` is running.
2. Check your `launchSettings.json`

   ```
   {
       "profiles": {
           "GrpcGreeter": {
               "commandName": "Project",
               "launchBrowser": false,
               "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
               "environmentVariables": {
                   "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Import `proto` to `bloomRPC`
4. Change `Server Address` to `0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: The change made to launchsettings.json did the job. Logically, I also stopped using TLS in bloomRPC.. The last step was not fully needed (localhost and 0.0.0.0 both work fine).

Comment: Where is this launchsettings.json file located ?

Comment: Thanks @Edward,
It's perfect working with **0.0.0.0:5000**.
But you have idea why it is not working with **0.0.0.0:5001**.
**0.0.0.0:5000** is working with HTTP &
**0.0.0.0:5001** is working with HTTPS.

Comment: This is obviously non-optimal because it isn't using https. It would be very nice to get this working properly with https.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually import your VisualStudio's certificate into the bloomRPC. Click on the TLS button next to the lock icon. You'll get a popup window where you can add your certificate by clicking on "Add Root Certificate". Use the base-64 encoded X.509 certificate.

`ssl target host` should be the hostname for which the ssl certificate is generated for, in your case it's `localhost`.

VisualStudio can create multiple certificates so you need to test which one of them is working for you.

Here are the steps how to export your VisualStudio's certificate from the MMC:
https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-installation/import-and-export-certificate-microsoft-windows

[image: Importing certificate to BloomRPC]